# Regular Expression Match only first character

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

I have this Regular Expression:

```
^([^6]*)6
```

I want it to match ONLY the first character and make sure its a 6. E.g.

60123456789

It should return 1 match

0123456789 should return 0 matches

How can I do this?

Currently the results it returns in my application is:
601234567890 returns an error

EDIT: This is a data annotation above my ViewModel property

```
[RegularExpression("^([^6]*)6", ErrorMessage = "Phone Numbers must start with a 6")]
```

Comment: How about `^6`?

Comment: ^6 will cause problems when there are more characters

Comment: /^6/.test('601234567890')

Comment: can you post your code along

Comment: `[^6]6` does this work or `[^\d]6`?

Comment: what should it return when it matches with a `6`? The complete number ... ?

Comment: @Acidic When I enter more numbers, the error appears. It should return nothing when it matches with 6. If the first character isn't a 6, then the error should appear.

Comment: if you want return nothing then you could `^(?=6)`

Comment: Hm.. i think you want something like `[^\d](6\d+)`?

Comment: I tried @guijob's solution and Acidic's solution and they both work the same way. If there is a 6 at the start of the input and nothing else, the error doesn't show. If I add more characters, the error appears.

Comment: And whats the desired behaviour?

Comment: How does `^(?=6)` works same way than `[^\d](6\d+)`? `^(?=6)` returns an empty match when first char is 6 and `[^\d](6\d+)` matches all numbers after 6 if 6 is first number found, not necessary in first position

Comment: The desired behaviour is this. The page loads and the input box already has a 6 in it. Then the user has to enter their phone number. if the user removes the 6, the error should appear.

Comment: You just need `"^6.*$"`, no need for parentheses. If you must invalidate `6nc-ded and more ?@#@@` input use `"^6[0-9]*$"`. Do you want to allow `6dhe%$^$%` like input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
'6123'.match(/^6(.+)$/)[0]
```

Where, 
'6123': is any number. 
For numbers starting with `6` it will match else it would return null.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Sorry how do I place this in the code in my question? The input is dynamic.

Comment: @JianYA, is this a jquery plugin ? It should work if you used the following string : `"^6(.+)$"`.

Comment: Its the .net core syntax